# Different Maven POM file to build and for repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

When we write POM file for a Maven project, it contains all the things needed to build including all kinds of dependencies, plugins etc.

But when we put a library into a Maven repository, say Maven Central, the most important thing needed is dependencies.

So we can use same or different POM files for this library to build and to distribute on Maven Repository.

However, in some cases, the POM file used to build cannot be used as the POM file on Maven Central.

For example, if you have system dependencies (it's a bad practice though), or if the build POM file relies on a parent POM in source tree to run. In this scenario, we should always different POM files.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If you have system dependencies where I assume you mean deps with `<scope>system</scope>` which should never do nor should you upload such things to Maven Central. It is not bad practice it's simply wrong. Some parts can sometimes be omitted like profiles for building. For this you can use things like the [flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/)...But you need to have the parent also being available from Central...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't think you answered the question. Are you saying that the best practice is to always use the same one, or?

Comment: In the end yes. Simple and easy. But there might be situations where you might need to use a different one which I think don't belong into maven central...may be into a corporate repository manager...as mentioned see flatten-maven-plugin...